# ionic3 error Unexpected directive 'ExpandableComponent' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation?

Tags: ionic3, expandable

i am working on a ionic 3 app in which we have create the custom expandable component from the CLI but it got below error in the console :

> Unexpected directive 'ExpandableComponent' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.

i have created ExpandableComponent and import in our app.module.ts fil.below our bapp.module.ts file

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { ServiceProvider } from '../providers/service';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http'
import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage';
import { ExpandableComponent } from '../components/expandable/expandable';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    HttpClientModule,
    ExpandableComponent,
   IonicStorageModule.forRoot()
  ],  
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    ExpandableComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
    ServiceProvider
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

```html
<ion-list>
<button (click)="expandItem(item)" *ngFor="let item of itemList">
    <ion-thumbnail item-start>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100">
    </ion-thumbnail>
    <h2>My Neighbor Totoro</h2>
    <p>Hayao Miyazaki • 1988</p>
    <expandable [expandHeight]="itemExpandHeight" [expanded]="item.expanded">
        Hello people
    </expandable>
</button>
</ion-list>
```

i have tried change the position of expandable component from module as well as entry component but not working.please tell me anyone what's the wrong in my code?